# Flutter Firestore Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE} automatically, Internet is working perfectly

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm building an app using Flutter and using Firestore as Backend . When I query something to Firestore. It works fine. But after 15-20 mintues when I query again(tapping on button and sending/retrieving  data) on Firestore. It shows me the following error shown in picture . When I tap again the query is then send. That means I have to press a button twice, when I'm in AFK(not using Phone or performing any action on Device)

V/NativeCrypto( 4054): Read error: ssl=0xbe39a7c8: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
V/NativeCrypto( 4054): Write error: ssl=0xbe39a7c8: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
V/NativeCrypto( 4054): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xbe39a7c8: I/O error during system call, Success
W/Firestore( 4054): (23.0.3) [WatchStream]: (a4f0ee) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=End of stream or IOException, cause=null}.
[cloud_firestore/unavailable] The service is currently unavailable. This is a most likely a transient condition and may be corrected by retrying with a backoff."

The error occurs after 15-20 mintues in the following picture
[image]

Comment: I have already tested its on a Physical Device/Android Emulator/Bluestack and others. The issue remain the same